# How can I synchronize Firefox settings between machines using MY server?

Tags: firefox, browser-plugin

I know that Firefox plugins exist to synchronize settings between machines, but all such plugins I have seen require you to synchronize your settings to some 3rd party server. Is anyone aware of such a plugin that:

1. You can synchronize to a server of your choice, including your home server, and
2. You can choose which settings or which bookmarks to synchronize to each machine, keeping NSFW bookmarks off your work machine, and
3. Synchronize settings between machines that are not on the same LAN or WAN

Answer (score 7):

When I last used it, Mozilla Weave was a slow unreliable flaky and busted piece of software. It may have improved in the past few months but in my experience:

1. Their servers were constantly down
2. It's slow
3. Firefox is always waiting to quit because sync is happening

Since then I've switched to [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) (formerly Foxmarks). It does support syncing to your own server. Documentation is [here](http://wiki.foxmarks.com/wiki/Foxmarks:_Using_Your_Own_Server).

Comment: +1 for Xmarks. I only use it for bookmarks at the moment though. Have two profiles, one for work and another for Home and it's been working well so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firefox Sync and run your own copy of their [Python-powered sync server](https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncserver), they have a detailed guide about it [here](https://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync-1.5.html).

You'll need a database server (anything supported by [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) will do, MySQL, SQLite, etc), a WSGI-compatible web server, and most likely a Linux or UNIX OS, I don't think this can easily be installed on Windows.

Once your server is up and running, go to `about:config` in all of your Firefox installations, and set the `services.sync.tokenServerURI` variable to your server's hostname + the `token/1.0/sync/1.5` path, such as `http://sync.example.com/token/1.0/sync/1.5`.